# Latin hypercube sampling for both float and integers

Tags: sampling, latin-hypercube

I am using Latin hypercube sampling to generate the combinations of 5 parameters. In these 5 parameters, the values of two parameters can be float numbers, while the values of three parameters must be integers in [0,10], [20,50], and [1,100]. Can anyone give an example for this?

Thank you!
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using R, this might be useful.  See the [lhs](https://github.com/bertcarnell/lhs) package for more information and other examples.

```r
require(lhs)
#> Loading required package: lhs
set.seed(14958393)
N <- 100
X <- lhs::randomLHS(N, 5)
Y <- as.data.frame(X)
names(Y) <- c("f1","f2","i1", "i2", "i3")
# map the continuous samples into the right distribution
Y$f1 <- qnorm(Y$f1, 2, 1)
Y$f2 <- qlnorm(Y$f2, 0.5, 0.1)
# translate the integer marginals
map_to_integers <- function(p, a, b)
{
  # p is a vector on (0,1)
  # a and b are integers
  floor(p*(b-a+1)) + a
}
Y$i1 <- map_to_integers(Y$i1, 0, 10)
Y$i2 <- map_to_integers(Y$i2, 20, 50)
Y$i3 <- map_to_integers(Y$i3, 1, 100)

# the distribution is not perfectly uniform because
N %% (10-0+1) != 0
#> [1] TRUE
table(Y$i1)
#> 
#>  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#>  9  9  9  9 10  8  9 10  9  9  9
# same here
N %% (50-20+1) != 0
#> [1] TRUE
table(Y$i2)
#> 
#> 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
#>  3  3  4  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  3  3  3  3  3  4  3  3  3  4  2  4  3  3  4  3 
#> 46 47 48 49 50 
#>  3  3  4  2  4
# but here, each one is sampled exactly once because
N %% (100-1+1) == 0
#> [1] TRUE
table(Y$i3)
#> 
#>   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
#>   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
#>  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40 
#>   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
#>  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60 
#>   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
#>  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80 
#>   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
#>  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
#>   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks a lot for your help. I just saw your post here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lhs/vignettes/lhs_faq.html and was trying to contact you. Then, I found you replied me here. I am using Python but I think I can learn R and use your code. Thanks a lot again!